# How to extrude vertices along a curve in consistent order?

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I'm trying to extrude faces (or vertices) along a curve to form a road-like shape.

However, I noticed that when I use the [`extrude`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Curve.html#bpy.types.Curve.extrude) property of the `Curve` object through a Python script and subsequently construct my own mesh object from these vertices, the order of vertices is inconsistent most of the time, resulting in a malformed shape:

[image: Failed extrude]

While sometimes it is not:

[image: Correct extrude]

In the end, I would like to export the generated mesh into a specific game format which relies on a fixed order of vertices in the mesh.

I have literally searched all over the web, but couldn't find an answer. Would this be possible with the Python API, or are there any libraries that I could use instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to memory corruption, because I was re-using the same `Curve` object over and over. I am not exactly sure why, but deleting the original curve object after copying it solved the problem.